# Check if object exists in a VB.NET dictionary using Primary Key

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary declared like this:

```
Dim customersDictionary As Dictionary(Of Customer, IList(Of String))
```

A Customer object is the key and for each customer object there is list of String values.

How would I return a bool checking to see if a customer with an id of 123 exists in the dictionary?

Comment: I think you may have built the dictionary wrong.  If the ID is unique use that as the key, then `customersDictionary.Contains(key)` will tell you if it exists.  Why is the value IList rather than a value like `"123"` or even `123` (int)?

Comment: It isn't built backwards I need the object itself as the key and then the value is a list of string. I know it seems strange but the dictionary used to be declared like this: Dim customersDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, IList(Of String)). Now instead of String I need to use a Customer object. I will primarily be using the CustomerId within the object though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just interested to know if a customer with the specified ID exists in your dictionary then you could write

```
dim result  = custList.Any(Function(x) x.Key.ID = 123)
if result then
    Console.WriteLine("Customer with ID=123 exists")
End if
```

Instead if you want to retrieve the customer given the ID then

```
dim result  = custList.Where(Function(x) x.Key.ID = 123).FirstOrDefault()
if result.Key IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim cust = result.Key
    Console.WriteLine("Customer Name is = " & cust.Name) ' or whatever property of your customer
End If
```